# Turn multiple separate objects into 1 array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the two Hash objects.

One:

```
{"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }
```

Two:

```
{"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" }
```

I am trying to take those two objects and turn them into something looking like this:

```
[{"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }, {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" } ]
```

How can I achieve this with javascript?

I'm also using underscore.

Also - When i have new object, I will receive more single objects I would like to push in like -

```
Three :   {"name" : "three" , "color" : "red" }
```

Result being -

```
 Result :        [{"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }, {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" }, {"name" : "three" , "color" : "red" } ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `[o1, o2]; _;` <--- yeah, it uses underscore!

Comment: Do you not have a fixed number of variables/objects in order to do what you did in your question? and Alexander's answer? Is the issue flexibility?

Comment: they will keep coming in 1 at a time, so I'd like to continuously push into this new object array @SmokeyPHP

Comment: @ajmajmajma What's wrong with `myArray.push(newObject)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var one = {"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }; 
var two = {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" };
var array = [one, two];
```

Or use push like so:

```
var array = [];
array.push(one);
//array is now equal to [one]
array.push(two);
//array is now equal to [one,two]
```

Or use unshift like this:

```
var array = [];
array.unshift(one);
// array is now equal to [one]
array.unshift(two);
// array is now equal to [two, one]
```

Essentially you just need to create variables to capture your Hash object values and use the variables you created to create an array.

You can additional values you can do this:

```
var three = {"name" : "three", "color" : "red" };
var array.push(three);
```

To display all values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var a = {"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }; 
var b = {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" };
var res = [a, b];
console.log(res);
```

or use push like so

```
var res = [];
res.push(a);
res.push(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an unkonwn number of objects, you'd use the`push` function of array:

```
var res = [];
var one = {"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }; 
var two = {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" };
res.push(one);
res.push(two);
// res is now: [{"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }, {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" }]
res.push({"name" : "three"});
// res is now: [{"name" : "one" , "color" : "red" }, {"name" : "two" , "color" : "blue" }, {"name" : "three"}]
```